# How to upload a back-end project on the Hostinger server

Tags: vds

I want to program an educational platform, and I do not know how to upload a back-end project on the Internet, knowing that it is using django Please reply because I couldn't find an explanation

Does it need a vps server?

Answer (score 1):

First, you must indicate you want to run your back-end project in a shared host or on your own VPS. If you are going to run on a shared host, you must ask the hosting support to provide Django modules (typically there are lots of limitations in the shared hosts due to security issues, and they don't provide some modules for clients).
In addition, if you have purchased a VPS you don't have any limitations to install all the modules you need.
Finally, if your host includes all necessary libraries and modules, you would upload the project's files and run it.